# Save dictionary to model object

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this one:

```
{'company_name': 'Google', 'title': 'headline', ...}
```

I know that i can store the values using this way:

```
user = User(company_name=data_db_form['company_name'], title=data_db_form['title']...)
```

However this is not good if I have many form fields.

There is any way to do this without hard code all the maps? The key value of the dictionary is the same of his model.

Comment: Have you tried just unpacking the dictionary? `user = User(**data_db_form)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
user = User(**data_db_form)
```

Here is the full example:

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, company_name='unknown', title='unknown'):
        self.company_name = company_name
        self.title = title

data_db_form = {'company_name': 'Google', 'title': 'headline'}

user = User(**data_db_form)

print user.company_name # prints Google
print user.title        # prints headline
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the dictionary using `for key, value in dic.iteritems():`, then in each iteration you have `company_name`, `title`, etc. in key and `Google`, `headline`, etc. in value.